# How do I restore an Item that has been archived in Sitecore 6?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have an Item that I archived that is still visible on the front end but is not appearing in the content editor. Is there any way to restore archived items?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sitecore 6 has a separate application for maintaining the archived items. Open Sitecore > All Applications > Archive and you'll see the archived items. There's a button Restore, which will do the job for you. :)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a way to restore archived items in Sitecore 6, but I have found a [blog post](http://usoniandream.blogspot.com/2007/07/tutorial-restore-from-archive.html) that shows how to create a custom command to do this in Sitecore 5.3.1.

Comment: I found this one too but I don't think the ArchiveItem class that is used exists in ver. 6. Thank you for the reply though.